# Telegram bot API no JSON POST data on webhook

Tags: telegram-bot

I can't seem to get the JSON POST data of the webhook. I set up everything correctly (the webhook URL, also tested if the server is getting POST requests) and the requests are coming when the user posts something, but no POST nor GET data is logged. Is this a common bug or is it just me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As they said:

> we will send an HTTPS POST request to the specified url, containing a JSON-serialized

It's a post, but they didn't mentioned any parameter for us to get it, just a JSON value, so try get the raw input.

For example in PHP I got it by using: `file_get_contents('php://input')`

Comment: OMG thanks! been struggling for a while, they should have put this in the docs (I was only logging $_REQUESTs thinking it's a $_POST request)

Comment: Hey do any of you know of a hack to somehow process the JSON without setting up a server - 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073962/setting-up-a-telegram-bot-without-a-server

Comment: I am getting an invalid JSON where keys have no quotes.. do you get that same one?

Comment: Please Help me this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519495/how-to-solve-disturbance-in-my-bot-in-c

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

A self signed cert is valid now.

Comment: It seems that the problem was in the way i was capturing requests (thought it was a $_POST request)

Comment: A self-signed certificate will work. Your answer is out-and-out wrong. However, a wildcard certificate will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Also, another reason for not getting POSTs is that the certificate chain could be incorrect. No errors show on Firefox, but Chrome for Android complained.

It's explained in this thread on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/Telegram/comments/3b4z1k/bot_api_recieving_nothing_on_a_correctly/

As soon as I added the chain certificate file and restarted Apache, the requests started coming in.