# Setting up a Telegram bot without a server

Tags: json, webhooks, telegram-bot

I'm not well versed with web techniques and would like to know if there's a way - an idea would be to use [setWebhook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook) - to make a [telegram bot](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) do simple stuff (like simply repeat the same message over and over again whenever someone sends it a message) **without setting up a server**.

I think there might be no way around it because I need to parse the JSON object to get the chat_id to be able to send messages... but I'm hoping someone here might know a way.

e.g.

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/setWebHook?url=https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage?text=Hello%26chat_id=<somehow get the chat_id>
```

I've tested it with a hard-coded chat id and it works... but of course it'll always only send messages to that same chat, regardless of where it received the message.

Comment: Have you looked at OpenShift? Three small "gears" are free, and make it easy to experiment **with** a server.

Comment: Ooo... thanks for the intro, I decided to just setup a server on Google App Engine, which is working just fine for now. I know it's stupid but here are the two bots I have running.

https://telegram.me/serhanbot
https://telegram.me/gregorybot

Answer (score 10):

Here is a very simple Python bot example, you can run this on your PC no need for a server.

```
import requests
import json
from time import sleep

# This will mark the last update we've checked
last_update = 0
# Here, insert the token BotFather gave you for your bot.
token = 'YOUR_TOKEN_HERE'
# This is the url for communicating with your bot
url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot%s/' % token

# We want to keep checking for updates. So this must be a never ending loop
while True:
    # My chat is up and running, I need to maintain it! Get me all chat updates
    get_updates = json.loads(requests.get(url + 'getUpdates').content)
    # Ok, I've got 'em. Let's iterate through each one
    for update in get_updates['result']:
        # First make sure I haven't read this update yet
        if last_update < update['update_id']:
            last_update = update['update_id']
            # I've got a new update. Let's see what it is.
            if 'message' in update:
                # It's a message! Let's send it back :D
                requests.get(url + 'sendMessage', params=dict(chat_id=update['message']['chat']['id'], text=update['message']['text']))
    # Let's wait a few seconds for new updates
    sleep(3)
```

[Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/Telegram/comments/3b1pwl/create_your_own_telegram_bot_stepbystep/)

[Bot I'm working on](https://github.com/Arlefreak/EightBallBot)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's a good answer and simple way - I see from your links you use Google server which is simpler than setting up your own.

Answer (score 0):

That's really interesting but definitely you'll need a server to parse the JSON value and get the chat_id out of it.

Comment: Is there any option to rub bot without **SSL** certification ?